# Why is my System event log full of WMI Performance Adapter messages?

Tags: wmi

The System event log continually shows these messages:

> The WMI Performance Adapter service
>   entered the running state.

and then

> The WMI Performance Adapter service
>   entered the stopped state.

Looks like it starts up every 2 minutes, then shuts down about 10 seconds later.

What are these messages from, and is this a normal thing or a sign of something bad happening?

My server is Windows 2008 Server.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you using System Center (or some other remote management console that uses WMI) to monitor\manage this system? That's what generally triggers those events in my experience. These are just events, not warnings\errors so there's no specific reason to panic and the rate isn't outrageous.

Answer (score 21):

The problem is caused by some other system (often SCOM) querying WMI-PA; when this happens, the service starts, processes, and then shuts down again -- leading to a huge bloat of system logs.

The solution is to set the **WMI Performance Adapter** Service to the "Automatic" startup type.  This will stop the launch/shutdown cycle.

(Ref: http://lokna.no/?p=1430)

Comment: Perhaps you could elaborate?

Comment: yes, see this link...  [http://lokna.no/wp-trackback.php?p=1430](http://lokna.no/wp-trackback.php?p=1430)  "set the startup type for the WMI Performance Adapter Service to Automatic" in the Host system SERVICES console in Administrative Tools/Control Panels. I had this same problem. - Link Credit Jan Kåre Lokna

Comment: Why is this downvoted? It's the correct answer.