# Side effects or performance issues for keeping WMI Performance Adapter running always?

Tags: windows, wmi

This is related to a similar question: [Why is my System event log full of WMI Performance Adapter messages?](https://serverfault.com/questions/108829)

I've found various blog posts that suggest you can modify the service so that it starts *Automatically*, thus preventing the event log from filling up. Is there any risk to this? Is there any performance penalty or any other side effect to keeping the service running all the time?